# Send the data from Salesforce into the email sent from Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, email-template, email-studio

I am trying to send an email whenever the case is closed in the Sales cloud. Below is the picture:
[image]

Now I am trying the pass the CaseId into the email sent from the journey because this email has the survey and I want to track the case for which the survey is being answered. This can be solved if I pass the CaseId in the Survey URL. But how do I pass the CaseId into the email sent from the journey builder when the entry source is salesforce data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields in the Entry Data are also the columns will be created the data extension.

You can render the Case Id in the email by using `AttributeValue` function.

In the email, you can put something like this:

```
%%[
set @caseId = AttributeValue("Case:Id")
]%%
```

And then you can use the `@caseId` to pass into your survey URL as the way you want.